# Why keras LSTM layer requires input shape?

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I am trying to create simple `RNN` in `keras` which will learn over this dataset:

```
X = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]])
y = np.array([[1], [1], [0], [1], [0]])
```

where 1s arrays is 1 and 2s arrays is 0

here is my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]])
y = np.array([[1], [1], [0], [1], [0]])

print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

but I'm getting the error:

> ValueError: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an
>   `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape` argument.

why does `LSTM` layer should have input shape? as I know, in theory, there can be different input shapes, cause this is recurrent neural network.

how to make my code work?

Comment: Could you print out `X.shape`?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko (5,)

Comment: Could you print it out? (I mean `X`)

Comment: @MarcinMożejko array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], dtype=object)

Comment: You need to make each list to have the same length. Keras is not accepting sequences of varying length.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko but this is my real task prototype. these arrays is natural language sentences.

Comment: So pad them all with `0s` to have equal length. If you want I may write an answer with details.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko detailed answer will be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your error comes from the fact that you need to some how specify the input shape to your model. In `Sequential` case you usually do that by setting `input_shape` in a first layer.

Now - the problem is in your input. With

```
X = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
Y = [[1], [1], [0], [1], [0]]
```

You will have problems because each sequence should have the same length. What I advise you to do is to use [`pad_sequences`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#pad_sequences)

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

X = pad_sequences(X)
Y = numpy.array(Y)
```

Now - as you mentioned - your task is a `MLP` task so it's good to use an [`Embedding`](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) layer:

```
from keras.layers import Embedding

vocabulary_size = 2 + 1 # Maximal word index + 1
sequence_length = 8 # Maximal length of a sequence
embedding_dimension = 20 # You could choose a different one

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, embedding_dimension, input_length=sequence_length)
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

I changed the `activation` to a `'sigmoid'` beacuse `'softmax'` wouldn't work with `1-d` output. Accordingly I changed loss to `'binary_crossentropy'`.

Comment: thank you. it works. how can I use predict method? when I write model.predict(X[0]), I'm getting: ValueError: Error when checking : expected embedding_input_1 to have shape (None, 8) but got array with shape (8, 1)

Comment: Try `model.predict(X[:1])`. Remember that you must provide a full-shaped matrix to your model during prediction.

Comment: Why not use masking? :) it's working fine with embeddings and LSTM used one after another.

Comment: it works! I see that Embedding layer requires vocabulary_size. In real app there will be arrays of floats from word2vec, e.g. not only 1 and 2, but any real number between 0 and 1. how to set vocabulary_size in that case?

Comment: @NassimBen - yes - masking could work fine. But I didn't want to make my answer even more complexed. In case - when you have embedding - then you could chop off the `Embedding` layer and feed vectors directly to `LSTM` layer.

Comment: I am curious why padding is required. In theory LSTM should be able to handle variable length. In keras documentation, the LSTM has an "unrolled" flag. When setting that to false (default), it will use a symbolic loop. In that case, why does it require a fixed input length? Because sentence length varies a lot, can go from two words to 20-30 words, padding the input to the longest sentence seems memory inefficient.